# How to say to typescript: "this two keys on that interface must have the same type"?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

First, I created it:

```
interface SomeInterface{
  param1: unknown
  callback: (body: unknown)=>void
}
```

look basic, right?
but I need something a little bit more specific...

what I need is a way to say to typescript: "the type of the value setted on param1, will be the same that is returned on callback"

Yes, I tried generic types, but it will be slow in some complex types

```
const someConstant:SomeInterface<{
  key1: Array<{subkey1: number, subkey2: string}>,
  key2: Record<string, number[]>
}> = {
  param1: {
    key1: [
      {subkey1: 5, subkey2: 'example'},
      {subkey1: 1.5, subkey2: 'example again'}
    ],
    key2: {
      anything: [1, 6, 2, 7]
    }
  },
  callback: (body)=>{
    console.log(body)
  }
}
```

In a nutshell, I dont want to specify the "" thing at the declaration, but if I define it to be unknown by default, the linter will think that "body" will be unknown too

And yes, I tried to use functions...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that suits your needs, but a generic `class` with `public` fields would solve your problem:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    constructor(public param1: T, public callback: (body: unknown) => T) { }
}

const obj1 = new SomeClass({ some: 'value' }, () => ({ some: 'value' })); // OK
const obj2 = new SomeClass({ some: 'value' }, () => ({ other: 'value' })); // KO

const assertEquals = (val1: any, val2: any) => console.log(JSON.stringify(val1) === JSON.stringify(val2));

assertEquals(obj1.param1, obj1.callback({})); // true
assertEquals(obj2.param1, obj2.callback({})); // false
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFAPAFQHzQG8AoaU6YeAOwgBcAnAV2BvjoAoAHBgIxAEtg0DmDphEARgBc0bABohPfoOBgQIbmGABraW27wAJgE9pDSlsrwA7pQCU0ALz5s9gtAC+RT0QrUa0eG4AK3FHaEpkKzgkNAwINjcIGOkAcgA3VQZkFI95NnsnaAToJJRUjJAsnPdbWwBuaAB6RugAeQBpHypaAOCAJjCIqIQUdEh4xOTodMzs3KKC-GL4GgALZDpy2erahubodtaiLr9ocY2aAFEARwZVGAciiqkzyiN5Cr7pMDfF8m74CBkAA6EDwADmbAAUrBWgA5YG0Oh8SjgvgAMyMbGeBQcjxh8MR9BRaMx2NUfV2x3OdCut3ubECIWBwlEEnkTPEwJUag02gSNXqRBpdLuIHiTL6LJEYnEHP63NU6k0WgFuyAA)

If you don't want a `class` you can write a plain `function` as a factory of objects that implement your interface. The point is you'll get type inference of a generic function (plain or constructor) thanks to its arguments types when calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You said generics, but I don't see how it can be slow on your `SomeInterface` type — you don't perform complex interactions or processing of the type itself. And usually, constraining it to some broad type or even `unknown` can help drastically with the performance.

You can point us to where it becomes slow, so it can be further investigated. For now, does a code like this work for you?

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
  param1: T
  callback: (body: T) => void
}

const someConstant: SomeInterface<{
  key1: Array<{ subkey1: number, subkey2: string }>,
  key2: Record<string, number[]>
}> = {
  param1: {
    key1: [
      { subkey1: 5, subkey2: 'example' },
      { subkey1: 1.5, subkey2: 'example again' }
    ],
    key2: {
      anything: [1, 6, 2, 7]
    }
  },
  callback: (body) => {
    console.log(body)
  }
}
```